# UIImageView Delay or revert to different frame

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Ok so I have been searching and have been unable to find an answers to this problem.  (And I assume I can't find it because it is a very easy answer that everyone seems to know but me.)  I am creating an app for IOS, where there is some opening animation and then I need the opening animation to stop and then different animation to take place instead.  So I have the opening animation working fine and I have it stopping on the last frame.  How do I get the new animation to start at the end of the opening animation?  I am using UIImageView under the viewDidLoad() function.  Here is my code for the ViewController.m file:

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize hook_drop_one;
@synthesize hook_swing_one;

- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    hook_drop_aone=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=1; i<16; i++) {
        NSString *hookpic=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"hook%d.png",i];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:hookpic];
        if (img) [hook_drop_aone addObject:img];
        [hook_drop_one setAnimationImages:(hook_drop_aone)];
        [hook_drop_one setAnimationDuration:0.9f];
        [hook_drop_one setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
        [hook_drop_one startAnimating];
    }

    hook_swing_aone=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=1; i<230; i++) {
        NSString *hookswingpic=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"hookswing%d.png",i];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:hookswingpic];
        if (img) [hook_swing_aone addObject:img];
        [hook_swing_one setAnimationImages:(hook_swing_aone)];
        [hook_swing_one setAnimationDuration:10.2f];
        [hook_swing_one startAnimating];
    }
}
```

My code fro the ViewController.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *hook_drop_one;
    NSMutableArray *hook_drop_aone;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *hook_swing_one;
    NSMutableArray *hook_swing_aone;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain)UIImageView *hook_drop_one;
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *hook_drop_aone;
@property (nonatomic,retain)UIImageView *hook_swing_one;
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *hook_swing_aone;


@end
```

Now I understand why both animations are running at the same time when the app loads.  I need to figure out how to trigger one animation after the first one stops, or set a delay for the second animation.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can using

```
 [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{ ... }]
```

please review session 421 WWDC 2011 - there is all info in second part of session.

Comment: I do not have access to the WWDC 2011 Conference.  It is saying I need to purchase a ticket.
I also tried the  [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{ ... }] and it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Use i for determining the timming for your next animation , or you can start animation by touch event.

Comment: Use value of i for that put the next animation in if block checking for the value for i like : if(i>=16){ then run next block}

Comment: ok so i must be missing something cause when I do that the animation doesn't start.  Do I need to put the code in a different place beside viewDidLoad?

Comment: You can use this code in same block as the first animation , just initialize the i in viewDidLoad and then use it for first animation , as i think when your first animation end the value for i will be 16. So you can use " If statement for If(i=>16) { next animation, just after the for loop of first animation}.